# iPhone SDK: Custom Tab Bar - How to use TweetBotTabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller

After searching on how to implement a custom tab bar for my iphone app, I came across the TweetBot Tab Bar located here [TweetBotTabBar](https://github.com/i300/TweetBotTabBar)

I downloaded the zip file and opened the Tweet Bot project in Xcode, however i'm not sure how to go about using it in my own app.

Do I have to import the TweetBot project into my own project or do I have to copy and paste the code separately?

My existing code uses the standard UITabBarController included in the SDK.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source file copy these files into your project

[image: Tabbar Files]

Then create your rootViewController and add a TBTabBar to the view, assign different viewcontroller to your different tabbars and implement TBTabbarDelegate inside.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TBTabBar.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<TBTabBarDelegate>{
    TBTabBar *tabBar;
}

@end
```

Implementation of this view controller will be as follow

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TweetBotTabBarTestViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)dealloc
{
    [tabBar release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TweetBotTabBarTestViewController *vc1 = [[TweetBotTabBarTestViewController alloc] init];
    TweetBotTabBarTestViewController *vc2 = [[TweetBotTabBarTestViewController alloc] init];
    TBViewController *vc3 = [[TBViewController alloc] init];
    vc3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    TBTabButton *t1 = [[[TBTabButton alloc] initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"timelineIcon"]] autorelease];
    t1.highlightedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"timelineIconHighlighted"];
    t1.viewController = vc1;
    TBTabButton *t2 = [[[TBTabButton alloc] initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mentionsIcon"]] autorelease];
    t2.highlightedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mentionsIconHighlighted"];
    t2.viewController = vc2;
    TBTabButton *t3 = [[[TBTabButton alloc] initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"messagesIcon"]] autorelease];
    t3.highlightedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"messagesIconHighlighted"];
    t3.viewController = vc3;
    TBTabButton *t4 = [[[TBTabButton alloc] initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritesIcon"]] autorelease];
    t4.highlightedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritesIconHighlighted"];
    t4.viewController = vc3;
    TBTabButton *t5 = [[[TBTabButton alloc] initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIcon"]] autorelease];
    t5.highlightedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIconHighlighted"];
    t5.viewController = vc3;
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, nil];
    tabBar = [[TBTabBar alloc] initWithItems:a];
    tabBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
    [tabBar showDefaults];
}

#pragma mark - TBTabbar Delegate
-(void)switchViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UIView *currentView = [self.view viewWithTag:SELECTED_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TAG];
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];

    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-(tabBar.frame.size.height));

    viewController.view.tag = SELECTED_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TAG;

    [self.view insertSubview:viewController.view belowSubview:tabBar];
}


@end
```